# Is it ok , if I install ubuntu linux mint and windows in C drive?

Tags: windows-7, syslinux

I already had windows 7 os , then I install linux mint 15 in c ,
now I want to have ubuntu in c ,

may it create any problem , because I have reached to maximum partition of my hard disk.
so can not create a seperate drive.

please assist me .

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning should look like:
1 - primary - windows or recovery partition
2 - primary - windows or recovery partition
3 - primary - boot partition
4 - extended partition container

5+ - up to eleven logical partitions.

If you find yourself running short on logical partitions because you're hydra-booting, look in to using LVM.